# How to tame negative CSS rotation?

Tags: svg, css-animations, keyframe

Seems that it is not possible to let two rectangles spin in the opposite direction. This leads to the output that the rectangle rotating in the reverse direction is placed lower.

```css
@keyframes gspin {
       from {transform:rotateZ(110deg);}
       to {transform:rotateZ(100deg);}
    }
    @keyframes spin {
       from {transform:rotateZ(70deg);}
       to {transform:rotateZ(80deg);}
    }
        #spinner {
             animation: spin 10s infinite; 
             transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          }
          #gspinner {
             animation: gspin 10s infinite;
             transform-origin: 50% 50%;
             z-index:0;
            }
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
    <g id="spinner">    
    <rect rx="10" height="20" width="400" y="195" x="160" fill="darkgrey"/>    
    </g>    
    <g id="gspinner">    
    <rect rx="10" height="20" width="400" y="195" x="160" fill="darkgrey"/>    
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `<g id="spinner">
   <rect rx="10" height="20" width="400" y="195" x="160" fill="darkgrey"/>
   </g>
   <g id="gspinner">
   <rect rx="10" height="20" width="400" y="195" x="160" fill="darkgrey"/>
   </g>`

I tried absolute transform-origin, with and without grouping, and negative animation sequences, without success,

Comment: may be containing some clue to a solution, mirroring? https://www.mediaevent.de/tutorial/svg-transform.html